# Scaling a range of numbers in PHP?

Tags: php, math

I'm developing some PHP code which is communicating with a piece of hardware which is moving a physical hand on a clock. Basically, I've got a range of numbers (minutes) between 000 and 180 which correspond to servo positions 000 to 180.

The problem I am facing is I now have found that the servo can only move to values between 000 and 165.

Is there a way of scaling a given number in the range of 000 to 180 to a range of 000 to 165? I've been racking my brains on this one, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Example function:

```
function convertScale($handVal)
{
 //some code to convert scale from 000-180 to 000-165
 return $convertedPos;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, it's much simpler than it seems! I'm alright with programming, I'm just rubbish at maths problems!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can it take floating point?

```
function convertScale($handVal)
{
    return $handVal * 165.0 / 180.0;
}
```

If not, rounding to nearest integer is hopefully okay:

```
function convertScale($handVal)
{
    return round($handVal * 165.0 / 180.0);
}
```

*---Edit---*
As alluded to in comments, a 3-digit string is easily provided by:

```
function convertScale($handVal)
{
    return sprintf ("%03d", round($handVal * 165.0 / 180.0));
}
```

Comment: It can't take a floating point, and has to be three digits long despite the number, so 10 would be 010. But I've got a pre-written function which rounds to the nearest number and creates a 3 digit number by converting to a string and using the strlen function.

Thanks for that help. I'm alright with programming, I'm just rubbish at maths problems!